# How to get user input result?

Tags: android

```
   public class Display{
   String value = null;
   public Dispaly(){}
   public  String showTestDialog() {
           final EditText edittext = new EditText(activity);
           alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();
           alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
           alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");
           alertDialog.setView(edittext);
           alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
                   new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                         value = String.valueOf(edittext.getText());


                           dialog.dismiss();
                       }
                   });
           alertDialog.show();
         return value;
       }
   }

   public class B{

      /* In class B I want to call function showTestDialog from Display 
         which  opens dialog and save user input in string. Is it possible? 
         Can someone please show me an example how to do it. Thanks a lot! 
      */

      Display display = new Display();
      String string = display.showTestDialog();
   }
```

Comment: Code formatting fix

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Display{
    Callback callback;
    public Dispaly(Callback callback){
    this.callback = callback;
}
    public  void showTestDialog() {
            final EditText edittext = new EditText(activity);
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");
            alertDialog.setView(edittext);
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                          Strint value = String.valueOf(edittext.getText());
                          callback.onUserInput(value)

                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }

    public class B{

    Display display = new Display(new Callback() {
    void onUserInput(String input){
   // DO WHAT you need
}
});
    display.showTestDialog();
    }

interface Callback { 
 void onUserInput(String input);
}
```

But is not a good code. I would have put this in DialogFragment and just call it. No callbacks. Then in the DialogFragment I woul have used MVVM so the DialogFragment will post the result in the ViewModel. Then from the ViewModel you can call what you need.